# Reference request for division algebras, over $\mathbb{Q}_{p}((t))$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

I was looking for a possible reference that would answer the following question,

Let $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ be the $p$-adic numbers and $\mathbb{Q}_{p}((t))$ be the field of Laurent polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$. Does anyone know of a reference that addresses the following question,

"Are all division algebras over $\mathbb{Q}_{p}((t))$ cyclic?"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "division algebra" I assume you mean a finite dimensional central algebra over $\mathbb{Q}_p((t))$, which is a divsion ring.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the closest result I know.  If the degree of the division algebra is a prime $q \ne p$, an affirmative answer has been given over finite extensions of $\mathbb Q_p(t)$ by Saltman's paper [Cyclic algebras over $p$-adic curves](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0604409).

There is also [an article of Brussels](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4419-6211-9_2) on Saltman's work.

Comment: Saltman's paper is working with the arithmetically trickier $\mathbb{Q}_{p}(t)$. But it is a good place to start. Thanks.

Comment: @TheNumber23 Ah, sorry, I had function fields on my mind when I saw your question, and didn't read it carefully.